# Not able to run ByteBuddy interceptor when @Morph argument is specified

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I need to create a custom classes based on some input. What I have atm is this:

```java
    final Class service = ...;
    final Method method = ...;

    final DynamicType.Unloaded unloadedType = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(Object.class)
        .name(service.getClass().getSimpleName() + "DynamicResolver")
        .defineMethod(
            endpointName,
            resolveReturnType(method),
            Modifier.PUBLIC)
       .withParameters(parameters)
       .intercept(MethodDelegation
            .withDefaultConfiguration()
            .withBinders(Morph.Binder.install(Morphing.class))
            .to(interceptor).andThen(
                MethodCall.invoke(method).on(service).withArgument(arguments)
            ))
       .make()
```

What I am doing here is creating a class with a single method that delegates to provided one. However, the created method and delegate method have a bit different parameters. The created method has one argument more (in `parameters`). The created method does not take that argument, hence the `arguments` array with argument indexes (one argument less).

So far it's OK. Now, I need to *add* additional argument when calling delegation method. For the sake of simplicity of the example, imagine we have to add one more string to delegate call.

As I saw from the documentation, the way to manipulate the arguments is using `@Morph`. So I did:

```java
public interface Morphing<T> {
    T invoke(Object[] args);
}
```

and my interceptor:

```java
public class Interceptor {
    @RuntimeType
    public Object invoke(
        @Morph final Morphing<Integer> m,
        @AllArguments final Object[] args
    ) {
        System.out.println("!!!");
        return m.invoke(args);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. When I remove the `@Morph` argument, the interceptor gets called.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Is the `@Morph` used only for subclasses and not when delegating to another instance?

EDIT2: [example](https://web.tresorit.com/l/BPvwM#luTWC-WqnkEAMeWydVSN4Q)

Comment: It looks correct, at least. How is it "not working"? Is an exception thrown or does BB select another method? You could run with `-Dnet.bytebuddy.dump=/some/folder` to see the result of the transformation.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter The `invoke()` is not invoked (I guess the interceptor not applied). In other words: when I DONT have `@Morph` argument it works (I see `!!!` in the console). Then I add the `@Morph` argument to the `Interceptor` and dont change anything else - and there is no `!!!` in the console.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter note that I am not subclassing a target class, but delegating a call to it. The documentation mention `@Morph` with subclassing. Maybe this has no sense what I said, but maybe since there is no subclass method call, there is no `@Morph` and therefore interceptor is not applied.

Comment: It looks correct. Try to add a filter to only select the method in question after 'withDefaultConfiguration()'.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter please check the added link - its a project that recreates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Byte Buddy is binding a method of the `Object` class such that your desired interceptor is no longer triggered. You can add `filter(isDeclaredBy(MyInterceptor.class))` after the `withDefaultConfiguration()` to avoid this. Doing so, you will get an exception that Byte Buddy cannot bind any of your methods.

The reason that `@Morph` makes the class ineligable is that there is no super method to be called. In your example, you are defining a new method which does not have an original implementation. You'd need to override an existing method to use the annotation.

Comment: Thanx, that was my reasoning as well - that without super method, @Morph would not make sense.